# "Cannot determine repositoryRootUrl for selected context" error in Netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

In Netbeans 7.2 for Mac, when I click on the "Refresh Status" icon in the Subversion panel, I get the following error:

> Cannot determine repositoryRootUrl for selected context:

And then the error message lists a path in my user directory.  The funny thing is that the path is to a website that has nothing to do with the open projects.

I've had this problem ever since I first setup this Mac.  I was previously using a Windows machine for developing my PHP websites.  I wonder if the error started because I copied all the project directories onto my Mac and somehow corrupted my Subversion setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try select the project in the Projects view and call Subversion -> Show 
changes from the context menu.

That should cleared the error.